# Still return JOIN result when no match

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, outer-join

I have a `join` in one of my queries but when the `join` returns nothing, the main query itself returns nothing and not sure how to still have query run when `join` fails.

```
SELECT 
"Wishlist".*, 
COUNT("WishlistItem".*) AS "wishlistItemCount" 
FROM "Wishlist" 
INNER JOIN "WishlistItem" 
ON ("WishlistItem"."wishlistId" = "Wishlist"."wishlistId") 
WHERE ((("Wishlist"."wishlistId" = $1) OR ("Wishlist"."userId" = $2)) 
AND 1=1) GROUP BY "Wishlist"."wishlistId" 
ORDER BY "Wishlist"."dateCreated" 
DESC
```

So I'm wanting the contents of `Wishlist` even when the `WishlistItem` count returns no match.

I attempted a `coalesce` on the `COUNT(*)` but that didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it from an inner join to a left outer join.

```
SELECT 
    "Wishlist".*, 
    COUNT("WishlistItem".*) AS "wishlistItemCount" 
FROM "Wishlist" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "WishlistItem" 
    ON ("WishlistItem"."wishlistId" = "Wishlist"."wishlistId") 
WHERE ((("Wishlist"."wishlistId" = $1) OR ("Wishlist"."userId" = $2)) 
    AND 1=1) GROUP BY "Wishlist"."wishlistId" 
ORDER BY "Wishlist"."dateCreated" 
DESC
```

Comment: Awesome that worked !! thanks will set as answer in 10 mins ;)